# Сайт не проходит гугл верификацию

Tags: битрикс, google-search

Есть сайт http://cheremiskin.ru/  на битриксе. Добавляю в корень хтмл файл гугла, но сайт  отдает 404   http://cheremiskin.ru/googlea1445ad7a93cba47.html

ДОбавил метатег   в хед, но гугл упорно не видит.

> Не удалось подтвердить

При этом с яндексом никаких проблем. 
Заметил, что если переименовать файл, убрав всего один символ, то сайт видит
http://cheremiskin.ru/googlea1445ad7a93cba4.html

Есть какие то мысли, как решить эту проблему?

UPD: решил проблему генерацией более простой ссылки. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: а `/` (слеш) в конце первой ссылки, если он есть уберите его.

Answer (score 1):

- ссылка оканчивающаяся на `/` не работает, уберите слеш, иначе это воспринимается как директория сайта
- вы неправильно добавили мета-тег google - он должен быть в `<head> ... </head>`, а у вас он вне `<html>` вообще. [Google Meta Tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=ru)